# ReactNative drawerNavigation custom footer

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I have a drawer navigation where I am trying to put a footer on the bottom which would contain additional info (app version and logout link) ..

This is my navigation container:

```
      <NavigationContainer style={styles.drawer}>
    <Drawer.Navigator style={styles.drawer} drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>

      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
            <Image source={require('./assets/icons/sidemenu-icon-account.png')} style={[{ height: 25, width: 25 }]} />
          )
        }} />

      <Drawer.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({ focused, size }) => (
            <Image source={require('./assets/icons/sidemenu-icon-account.png')} style={[{ height: 25, width: 25 }]} />
          )
        }} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>);
```

And this is the custom content:

```
    function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    
    <DrawerContentScrollView style={styles.drawer}  {...props}>
      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
        <Image source={require("./assets/logo.png")} style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", resizeMode: "contain" }} />
      </View>

      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flex: 1 }}>
              <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text>Log Out</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
      
  );
}
```

How can I push the log out link to be fixed at the bottom?
[image]

Styles:

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  img: {
    height: 40,
    width: 40,
    marginTop: 6,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },

  logout : {
    backgroundColor: 'red' ,
    bottom: 0,
    position: 'absolute'
  },

  logoContainer: {
    height: 140,
    width: "80%",
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  drawer: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    flex:1

  },
  labelBottom : {
    position: 'relative',
  bottom:0
  },

  redBottom: {
  },
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a  marginTop: 'auto' style for TouchableOpacity, also use the contentContainerStyle for scrollviews

```
function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.drawer} {...props}>
 <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
        <Image source={require("./assets/logo.png")} style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%", resizeMode: "contain" }} />
      </View>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <View>
          <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 'auto' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            flexDirection: 'row',

          }}>
          <Text>Log Out</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry but does not seem to have any effect!

Comment: Does the styles.drawer has flex:1 ? can you share that?

Comment: I'm checking will try to create a snack n will get back

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `style` prop, you may use `contentContainerStyle`:

```
<DrawerContentScrollView
   ...
   contentContainerStyle={styles.drawerContentContainer}
/>
```

while the style is something like:

```
drawerContentContainer: {justifyContent: 'space-between', flex: 1},
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by wrapping all the contents of my DrawerComponent inside a View element and then adding height: '100%' in the style prop of the root View element.
And finally adding marginTop: 'auto' will push the FooterComponent at the bottom (or you can use {position: 'absolute', bottom: 0} for style prop of FooterComponent).

```js
<View style={{height: '100%'}}>
  <HeaderComponent />
  <DrawerItems {...props} />
  <View style={{marginTop: 'auto'}}>
    <FooterComponent />
  </View>
</View>
```